# OneToMany Relations with Lift

Tags: scala, relational-database, lift

I have a question once again and I have the feeling the solution is simple. Should be simple, in any case. I have been trying to model my mappings for my database, with the nice `OneToMany` trait, like so

```
class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] with OneToMany[Long, User] {
  def getSingleton = User

  object posts extends MappedOneToMany(Post, Post.author, OrderBy(Post.edited, Descending))
}

class Post extends LongKeyedMapper[Post] with IdPK with OneToMany[Long, Post] {
  def getSingleton = Post

  object author extends LongMappedMapper(this, User)

  object title extends MappedString(this, 100) {
    override def dbIndexed_? = true

    override def defaultValue = "New Post"
  }

  object contents extends MappedText(this)

  object edited extends MappedDate(this)
}
```

All nice an done, I have my One-to-many relationship all right. But, what troubles me a real lot, how do I actually *get* the data in that relationship? Just supposing I've got a `Post` object and want to get the author's name to it?

```
bind("post", in, "title" -> post.title, "author" -> /* insert overly complicated method here */)
```

I've learned I can get it over a `Box`, by `post.author.obj` or something. It does not quite work out, I have to do a `match` over it and such?

I feel the answer is simple, but yet I fail to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapper does not guarantee you that `post.author` can always succeed, so it must return a `Box`. You could use a `post.author.obj.map(_.name.is) openOr "unknown name"` or similar to avoid using a `match` statement.

Alternatively, you could create a helper method on `Post` which does the default handling and use that instead.

Comment: Though I seem to have to do `post.author.obj.map(_.name.is) openOr "unknown"`, otherwiese I get type errors en masse, but thanks!

Comment: You’re correct. otherwise, you’ll get the field itself not its value. I fixed it.

Comment: You can try dmap as well - post.author.obj.dmap("unknown")(_.name.is).

Answer (score 3):

```
post.author.obj.map(_.userNameOrSomething).openOr("Unknown writer")
```